# Openssh installation problems

Tags: make, openssh

I'm new with Ubuntu, and I want to install `open-ssh` from source code.
when I type `make` and `make install`, the following errors appear:

```
pc@pc~/Desktop/openssh-7.6p1$ make**
(cd openbsd-compat && make)
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pc/Desktop/openssh-7.6p1/openbsd-compat'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pc/Desktop/openssh-7.6p1/openbsd-compat'

pc@pc:~/Desktop/openssh-7.6p1$ make install
(cd openbsd-compat && make)
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pc/Desktop/openssh-7.6p1/openbsd-compat'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pc/Desktop/openssh-7.6p1/openbsd-compat'
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/bin
make: execvp: ./mkinstalldirs: Permission denied
Makefile:313: recipe for target 'install-files' failed
make: *** [install-files] Error 127
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Please use code formatting for terminal output. See https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not sure if you really want to build `open-ssh` from source.

Apart from that it is pretty straight forward

```
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/bin
make: execvp: ./mkinstalldirs: Permission denied
```

Tells you that you do not have sufficient privileges to make changes to `/usr/local/bin`

You either have to get those priviliges e.g. by `sudo`

```
sudo make install
```

or you change the path where you want the software to be installed to something, where you have proper permissions e.g.

```
./configure --prefix=/home/user/locally_build
```

(replace the path obviously) and then repeat `make` and `make install`